# How to compare two excel data and write into new excel file

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x

I have two csv file, 1. master_test.csv 2. child_test1.csv 3. output.csv

master_test.csv contains following information

nnn

bbb_12

kkk

ccc

child_test1.csv contains following information

nnn

ddd

mmm

bbb_13

I need to compare the child_test1.csv data to master_test.csv file. finally write into output.csv file.
i need out put as below

nnn      nnn       Match found

ddd      ---       Not found Master sheet

mmm      ----      Not found Master sheet

bbb_13  bbb_12     Not Match or Version change

I am new to python, as of now i have tried the below code,
I m able to achieve match found in the same coloum[but i need out as above output.csv file]

after running the above code i got output as

nnn

match nnn

but i need output as below.

nnn       nnn    Match found

ddd      ---      Not found Master sheet

mmm      ----     Not found Master sheet

bbb_13   bbb_12   Not Match or Version change

please can any one can guide me

```
f1 = open("C:\\Python34\\master_test.csv", "r")
f2 = open("C:\\Python34\\child_test1.csv", "r")
outFile = open("C:\\Python34\\output.csv", "w")

fileOne = f1.readlines()
fileTwo = f2.readlines()

f1.close()
f2.close()
for i in fileOne:
    for x in fileTwo:
        if (x == i):
            outFile.write(i +"Equal " + x)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this

```
  f1 = open("C:\\Python34\\master_test.csv", "r")
    f2 = open("C:\\Python34\\child_test1.csv", "r")
    outFile = open("C:\\Python34\\output.csv", "w")

    fileOne = f1.readlines()
    fileTwo = f2.readlines()

    f1.close()
    f2.close()
    for i in fileOne:
        for x in fileTwo:
            writer = "{} --- Not found Master sheet".format(i)
            if (x == i):
                writer = "{} {} match found".format(i,x)
            outFile.write(writer+'\n')

This will keep the message in writer always that BlahBlahBlah! not found un master, But in case it is found then the writer will change to Blah Blah match found 


Hello
thank you for your reply,
But above code is not solved my issue,



 f1 = open("C:\\Python34\\master_test.csv", "r")
f2 = open("C:\\Python34\\child_test1.csv", "r")
outFile = open("C:\\Python34\\Aoutput.csv", "w")

fileOne = f1.readlines()
fileTwo = f2.readlines()

f1.close()
f2.close()
outFile.write("Match found\n")
for i in fileOne:
    for x in fileTwo:

        if (x == i):
         output.write(x)#Match found

output.write("Match not found")
#similar way if check 
for i in fileOne:
   for x in fileTwo:
      if (x != i):
         output.write(x) 
#Its writing all the combination, I need only not match from child values i.e
```

ddd

mmm